# Maintain the status of events in multithreading

Tags: java, exception, design-patterns, architecture, bigdata

I want to read records (1000k) from 1 table and push them to some service.

So I have clubbed 200 records(based on the service limitations) in 1 event and used the executor framework and have created 10 executors. 10 events will be processed (i.e. 10*200 records) parallelly.

Now I want to maintain the status of these events, like statistics on how many were processed successfully and how many failed.

So I was thinking of

**Approach 1:**
Before starting the execution,
writing each event id + record id with status

```
event1 + record1 -> start
```

and on completion

```
event1 + record1-> end
```

And later will check how many have both start and end in the file and how many do not have end.

**Approach 2 :**
Write all record ids in one file with status pending and
writing all successful records in another file

And then check for the missing in the successful file by using pivot

Is there a better way to maintain the status of the records?

Comment: Do you need to know which ones failed or all you need to know is the success failure ratio like: 98%

Comment: @PeterCsala Need to know the failed records. To reprocess them later

Comment: So, basically do need a dead letter queue?

Comment: Yes, kind of dead letter queue, But I am not using any queuing mechanism here

Comment: 2 more questions: Do you determine the failure by not having an end timestamp after a grace period? In case of retry the record id will be the same but the event id different, right?

Comment: In the first approach, the end timestamp will not be written to the file if an exception occurs, So without an end i will consider it as failure

Comment: " In case of retry the record id will be the same but the event id different, right" >> Yes

Comment: I have added event id to identify which batch failed i.e. which all records failed of a batch failed

Comment: With approach # 1, did you mean write to the database from which you source your records?

Comment: @BasilBourque write to a file

Comment: (A) Do you have a database? You said “table”? If so, why not write results in that database? (B) What volume of data? “1000k” is a million, but “10*200” is only 2,000.

Comment: I meant in 10 threads it will run 10*200 (1 event has 200 records) at a time

Answer (score 0):

In my view, if you want to process items parallelly, then it is better to create a log file by your amount of records. Why? Because one file is a bottleneck for multithreading, because you need to lock file to prevent [conditon race](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550/). If you will decide to lock file, then each thread should wait when log file will be released and waiting of file will nullify all multithreading processing.

So one batch should have one log file.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and start threads with the passed id so they can write to the array cell by their id.
The main thread will read this array and print it.
You can use ReadWriteLock (threads will hold the read lock to write and the main thread will hold the write lock while reading the entire array).
You can store anything in this array, it can be very useful.